# How to convert strings of date ranges into usable JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, date, solr, momentjs

I am getting a bunch of date ranges from a Solr index, which comes to me in this format:

```
[
  "[2016-11-02 TO 2016-11-02]",
  "[2016-11-16 TO 2016-11-16]",
  "[2016-11-05 TO 2016-11-08]",
  "[2016-11-09 TO 2016-11-09]",
  "[2016-11-11 TO 2016-11-12]",
  "[2016-11-10 TO 2016-11-10]"
]
```

I guess this is some kind of standard syntax for Solr, but how can I convert it to something useful in JavaScript, eg something like:

```
[
  {
    start: "2016-11-02",
    end: "2016-11-02"
  },
  {
    start: "2016-11-16",
    end: "2016-11-16"
  },
  ...etc
]
```

**I am already using MomentJs in the project, so that's an option as well**

Answer (score 5):

You could take a regular expression for the parts and map the new objects.

```js
var data = [ "[2016-11-02 TO 2016-11-02]", "[2016-11-16 TO 2016-11-16]", "[2016-11-05 TO 2016-11-08]", "[2016-11-09 TO 2016-11-09]", "[2016-11-11 TO 2016-11-12]",  "[2016-11-10 TO 2016-11-10]"],
    result = data.map(function (a) {
        var m = a.match(/^\[(.+) TO (.+)\]$/);
        return { start: m[1], end: m[2] };
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: The regular expression can be `a.match(/[\d-]+/g)` to save some typing. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, it needs to iterate the matched result set.